# Is there any parameter/attribute can differentiate the first_open from iOS and Android by using firebase cloud function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-analytics

I have two apps, one is iOS and the other is Android. They are all using the firebase service, wondering for the event `first_open`, how to tell they are from iOS or Android by firebase cloud function code?

I have:

```js
exports.newInstall = functions.analytics.event('first_open').onLog((event) => {
// code
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_analytics_.analyticsevent) for analytics events, there is no field that contains the platform for the event object delivered to the function.

Getting the platform sounds like a feature request, to be directed to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).